# Trigger scripts on git ci/cd after merge committed

Tags: git, automation, release, git-merge

I want to do some script calling from git ci/cd.
the first script should be executed when merge request are  thrown, then after the request are committed by admin, I want to execute another script

this is my code on .yml right now :

```
script1:
  script: 
  - sshpass -p password ssh user@host "cmd.exe /c powershell.exe path\to\local\script1"  
  only:
  - merge_requests

script2:
  script: 
  - sshpass -p password ssh user@host "cmd.exe /c powershell.exe path\to\local\script2"  
  stage: deploy
```

with these code, git ci still execute my script2 when the merge request is thrown, and also deploying my master branch after the request is commited.
I only want to execute the script described on my script2 code without any deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I use only on my target branch.

this is the final code that I'm using:

```
script1:
  script: 
  - sshpass -p password ssh user@host "cmd.exe /c powershell.exe path\to\local\script1"  
  only:
  - merge_requests

script2:
  script: 
  - sshpass -p password ssh user@host "cmd.exe /c powershell.exe path\to\local\script2"  
  only:
  - mytargetbranch
```